# Ant java task pass argument value with quotes

Tags: java, xml, ant, special-characters, izpack

I have situation where i have to pass argument with quotes from ant java task.

Argument to pass: `test"Argument`

My ant java task is as below :

```
<java classname="ClassName" failonerror="true" dir="path" fork="true">
    <classpath>
        //loading libraries here
    </classpath>    
    <arg value="test&quot;Argument" />
</java>
```

Java Code :

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        String input = args[0];
        System.out.println("*********  Passed Argument  : " + input);
    }
}
```

When i execute above code i got below output :

```
Buildfile: D:\GIT_615\OIM-OAM\OpsHubInstaller\BaseInstaller\Installer Resource\build.xml
stepName:
antTargetName:       
     [echo] Argument to pass: test"Argument
     [java]  *********  Passed Argument  : testArgument
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 563 milliseconds
```

If you see here double quote `"`or `&quot;` was not passed properly.

How can i pass argument with quotes to java file properly

Comment: Your Ant build file is correct.  The problem appears to be with the Java program that is being run by the `<java>` task.

Comment: @VGR I have added java code where i parse argument, can you tell me whats wrong with it ?

Comment: When I run that, I see: `*********  Passed Argument  : test"Argument`

Comment: @VGR Which ant version are you use ? I'm using 1.10.3

Comment: I’m using Ant 1.10.5.  I doubt it upgrading will make a difference, but you can try.